# Которые или которых?

Tags: согласование

"Мир полон тайн, которые нам не постичь" - написала я. Мне предлагают изменить на "которых нам не постичь". Кто из нас прав и почему?

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется этот вопрос чисто стилистическим. Глагол "постичь" с отрицательной частицей "не" -  согласуется с В. и Р. падежами :
*тайну не постичь*, *тайны не постичь*.
Таким образом, мы имеем возможность согласовать союзное слово *которых* и с существительным *тайн*, и с глаголом *не постичь* в одном падеже - родительном.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо! Поправьте, если я неправильно поняла: возможны оба варианта, но "которых" выигрышнее, потому что идёт согласование и с "тайн", и с "не постичь"?

Comment: Да, именно так.